# How to break line within a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here's my code:

```
user_input = input("Enter a saying or poem: ")

words_list = user_input.split()

words_list_length = len(words_list)


def word_mixer(words_list):

    words_list.sort()

    final_list = []

    if(len(words_list) <= 5):

        final_list = words_list 


    else:

        while(len(words_list) > 5):

            first_word_popped = words_list.pop(-5)

            final_list.append(first_word_popped)

            second_word_popped = words_list.pop(0)

            final_list.append(second_word_popped)

            third_word_popped = words_list.pop(-1)

            final_list.append(third_word_popped) 

    return final_list
```

So what I want is to break to a new line at the end of the while loop, so that when the code exits the while loop, the elements in the final_list variable are printed (or accomodated) 3 by 3 since it appends 3 elements in each iteration. I've seen people use the join() method but I'm not sure how to implement it here in case that's how I should solve the problem.

I've updated the code so you guys could get more context. An example input would be: "Hello there, this is a string input given by the user". An expected output would be :

```
string given user
Hello this by
```

As you can see, the string was sorted and it should print  (if I added a print statement to my code, of course) 3 words in each row. But I can't find a way to do it.

This exercise is from a Python course I'm taking in the edx.org page. There, they give this input/output example:

[image]

Just ignore the words being turned to upper/lower case. But as you can see, the list is printed 3 by 3 by adding a "\n" to the list. How do I do that?

Comment: Please add some of the expected input and outputs as it seems to me that a simpler solution could exist.

Comment: I see you have extended your code, but you haven't wrote a single input/output example. Please add the expected input and outputs.

Comment: I'm sorry about that. I just did it. I hope it helps you understand. If not, let me know and I'll try to explain it another way

Comment: Could you add more input/output example? What is the expected rule for dropping some of the words?

Comment: prefer text to images because latter ones are harder to work with

Comment: I just updated the post. Hope it helps you understand what I want to do

Comment: It seems like you want the final output as a 2 dimensional array, something like this [['input', 'Hello', 'user'], ['a', 'there', 'the']], for your original example "Hello there, this is a string input given by the user", Then you get a group of words as a list and access each list separately. You can put "\n" at the end of each list while printing but the idea is to group the words as one list and create a list of lists ... is that what you want?

Comment: Also, are you just interested in printing it that way? If so, you can just add a "\n" while printing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to print, you can print it inside the loop itself with a "\n" at the end of the loop. But if you want to store it in a format where you can use each group of words separately, then you could do something like:

```
words_list = ["Hello", "there", "this", "is", "a", "string", "input", "given", "by", "the", "user"]
final_list_2 = list()
while(len(words_list) > 5):
    final_list = list()
    first_word_popped = words_list.pop(-5)
    final_list.append(first_word_popped)
    second_word_popped = words_list.pop(0)
    final_list.append(second_word_popped)
    third_word_popped = words_list.pop(-1)
    final_list.append(third_word_popped) 
    final_list_2.append(final_list)

for final_list in final_list_2:
    print (" ".join(final_list))
```

OUTPUT:

`input Hello user
a there the`

Comment: but where would you put the "\n" exactly?

Comment: after each element of final_list_2 in my code sample above. I have a print in the `for final_list` loop which automatically prints each list on a newline.

Comment: Oh I see, I know it was something silly but I just couldn't find the right place to put it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So you need to append a new line for every three words, this is simple...

```
LIST = ["or", "brushed", "thy", "not", "little", "though", "me?", "summers?", "thee?"]
# Insert the new line
for i in range(len(LIST)):
    if i%3==0 and i>0:
        LIST.insert(i, "\n")
# Join the sentence
para = " ".join(LIST)
# Print the result
for i in para.split("\n"):
    print(i.strip())
```

you will get.

```
or brushed thy
not little
though me? summers? thee?
```